# Looking for help on a python project

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to coding and am trying to do a project to help me learn the basics and help my girlfriend with her tattoo pricing any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def tattoo_pricing(total_price):
    `total = [] + 40
    total_hours = input('how many hours roughly are you going to be tattooing?:')
    if total_hours[0] == 1:
        total += 60
    elif total_hours[0] == 2:
       total += 120`
```

I wanted to just multiply the total hours times 60 but don't understand how to grab the input.

any help would be greatly appreciated :) sorry im only a few months into my course right now, but i feel like this is near my skill level im just having alot of truble since ive only done one other project on my own

Comment: You seem to intentionally abuse `#` for some reasons. It does not work here, so please stop. You my want ti correct question formatting,.

Comment: Alright thank you sorry i'm new to this site and didn't know the post would look like this thanks for the help

Comment: @Namastex3 In your code, `total_hours` is array or variable ???

Comment: I was using examples from my course, and an arrays the only way i currently understand how to grab the input, but maybe this is out of my skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `input` gives you a string.

For example

```
>>> a = input()
12
```

The `a[0]` is `'1'` while `a[1]` is `'2'`.

The example from your course use each of the character to do something else. But in your case you just need

```
total = int(input('how many hours roughly are you going to be tattooing?:')) * 60
```

Or

```
total_hours = input('how many hours roughly are you going to be tattooing?:')
total = total_hours * 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the first item in the array (argument 0 if it is run from the command line) is the number of hours? Assuming total_hours[0] is the number of hours then you can do the following.

```
def tattoo_pricing(total_hours):
    total = 40
    total_hours = input('how many hours roughly are you going to be tattooing?:')
    total += 60 * int(total_hours[0])
```

This will make a total equal to 60 per hour plus what seemed to be a baseline of 40.

Comment: yeah that was what i was going for thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Also if this is what you wanted you can mark at as the answer so other people know you are all set.